# Way to limit the calendar selection in Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form that consists of questions that require a Date selection. Is there a way to limit the calendar picker to certain dates only? For example, if today is May 8, then the user can only choose a date that's more than or equal to 14 days or not more than 180 days  -  which will be from May 22 - November 3.

I couldn't find any reference in google apps script documentation regarding this so I'm hoping someone can make recommendations. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you need to use custom HTML form and then create the `FormResponse` programmatically. This will let you provide richer feedback to the user while they are filling it out, including automatic "days until" calculation and display, date picker validation, etc.

Comment: Is there a documentation regarding this that I can refer to?  I'm new to google apps script and have been searching for it since last week.

Comment: no, that's basic HTML form building. As far as creating a response programmatically, yes, the methods are described in documentation.

Comment: You mean i have to create a new HTML file inside Google Apps script?

Answer (score 2):

In order to have apply validation / rejection / limitations to Date / Time / Datetime responses in a Google Form, you need to implement your own HTML form, because (as of 2018 May 07) there are no validation settings for Google Form [`DateItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/date-item), [`DateTimeItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/date-time-item), [`TimeItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/time-item), or [`DurationItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/duration-item)s. Where you host your custom HTML form does not matter - you could use your own webserver, or you can use Apps Script & [`HtmlService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/), as a [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) or [webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

If you want to use Google Forms to manage the responses, then your solution is required to eventually connect with an Apps Script backend, since only Apps Script has [API access to Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) (there is no REST API like there is for Sheets or Drive). If you don't need to use Google Forms to manage responses, then you can do whatever you want with the responses (such as store them in your database-of-choice).

---

### Getting Data to Apps Script `.gs` files

#### Self-Hosted Form

A self-hosted form will need a published Apps Script webapp to interact with. Your form's submit action should send the data via HTTP POST request to the  webapp's url, and your Apps Script project will use a [`doPost(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters) trigger function to accept the data transfer.

#### HtmlService (Sidebar or Webapp Form)

Hosting the form via `HtmlService` means your client-server communication must use the `google.script.___` methods, which provide asynchronous behavior. Your form's submission action should either invoke a `doPost(e)` trigger function as above, or use [`google.script.run.someMethodInAgsFile(yourFormDataObject)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) with appropriate client-side success and failure handlers, for displaying the response back from Apps Script.

---

### Consuming the input data

Whichever hosting method you use, your custom form's data will eventually reach Apps Script, and you will need to construct a Google Forms [`FormResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) that you can programmatically submit to your desired Google Form. Note that programmatic form submissions do not activate 'on form submit' trigger events, because they are not user actions. If you have some programmatic event that should occur as a result of form submissions, simply call that same event from your code that did the submitting.

You can view the format of the input event object `e` in Apps Script documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters

The specifics of converting the input event object into your form data are dependent on your implementation, e.g. you may have named properties, a generic array, etc. An example `doPost` showing how to construct and submit the `FormResponse`:

```
function doPost(e) {
  console.log(e); // Log the object in Stackdriver, to allow easy viewing of its structure.
  if (!e) throw new Error("doPost Function called without event object.");
  if (!e.postData.length) throw new Error("No form data present.");

  var formData = /* construct your form data object, using some method to associate
                  between a question and the answer, like its index, the title, etc. */;
  var form = FormApp.openById("your form id");
  if (!form.isAcceptingResponses()) throw new Error("Form is closed to new input.");

  var toSubmit = form.createResponse();
  // Check every item in the form to provide the relevant answers.
  form.getItems().forEach(function (item, itemIndex, allItems) {
    // To create the item's response, you must cast it to its type
    // (since each item type has a different format for the answer).
    var it = item.getType(),
        itemResponse = null;
    if (it === FormApp.ItemType.DATE) {
      item = item.asDateItem(); // Cast this item to its type
      var answer = /* Use your formData object, for example use the index property,
          e.g. formData[itemIndex] if you made formData an array of the input data. */;
      itemResponse = item.createResponse(answer);
      /* do ItemType-specific stuff with the ItemResponse */
    } else if (it === /* some other item type you use */) {
      ...
    } else {
      throw new Error("Unhandled item type");
    }
    if(itemResponse) {
      /* do generic stuff with the item response */
      toSubmit.withItemResponse(itemResponse);
    }
  });
  // Submit the FormResponse now that it has been given answers for its items.
  toSubmit.submit();
}
```